# Run a TCP server listening for incoming messages

Tags: python, design-patterns, multithreading, socket

I've written the following code, but I need some review on design style.  I want to develop a library/module and expose an API to client programs. How do I do that?

The code just runs a TCP server listening for incoming messages and another thread accepting user input to send messages.

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys;
import socket;
import select;
import thread;
import pickle;
import struct;
import time;
import threading;


class AgTime:
    lClock=0;
    pClock=0;
    count=0;

#NTP client object that queries NTP server for time.
class Ntp:

    def __init__(self):
        # # Set the socket parameters 
        self.host = "pool.ntp.org"
        self.port = 123
        self.buf = 1024
        self.address = (self.host,self.port)
        self.msg = '\x1b'+47*'\0'
        # reference time (in seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00)
        self.TIME1970 = 2208988800 # 1970-01-01 00:00:00

    def time(self):
        # connect to server
        client = socket.socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        client.sendto(self.msg, self.address)
        data, address = client.recvfrom( self.buf )

        retval=struct.unpack("!12I",data);
        t = retval[10]
        t -= self.TIME1970
        return t;

class server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,portNo):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self);
        self.PORTNO=portNo;
        self.server_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
        self.server_socket.bind(("",self.PORTNO));
        self.CONNECTION_LIST=[];
        self.RECV_BUFFER=4096;

    def run(self):
        self.server_socket.listen(10);
        self.CONNECTION_LIST.append(self.server_socket);
        print "Server started on port :"+str(self.PORTNO);

        while(1):
            read_sockets,write_sockets,error_sockets=select.select(self.CONNECTION_LIST,[],[]);
            for sock in read_sockets:
                if sock==self.server_socket:
                    sockfd, addr= self.server_socket.accept();
                    self.CONNECTION_LIST.append(sockfd);
                    print "Message rxd from (%s %s)",addr
                else:
                    try:
                        data=pickle.loads(sock.recv(self.RECV_BUFFER));
                        if data:
                            thread.start_new_thread(recv,(data,));
                    except:
                        sock.close();
                        self.CONNECTION_LIST.remove(sock);
                        continue;
        self.server_socket.close();

def recv(data):
    lock.acquire();
    global time_stamp;
    t_message=data;
    t_stamp= {'pClock':0, 'lClock':0,'count':0};

    #recv part of algorithm starts from here
    t_stamp['lClock']=max(time_stamp['lClock'],t_message['lClock'],time_stamp['pClock']);
    if(t_stamp['lClock']==t_message['lClock'] and t_stamp['lClock']==time_stamp['lClock']):
        t_stamp['count']=max(time_stamp['count'],t_message['count'])+1;
    elif (t_stamp['lClock']==time_stamp['lClock']):
        t_stamp['count']=time_stamp['count']+1;
    elif(t_stamp['lClock']==t_message['lClock']):
        t_stamp['count']=t_message['count']+1;
    else:
        t_stamp['count']=0;

    time_stamp['lClock']=t_stamp['lClock'];
    time_stamp['pClock']=t_stamp['pClock'];
    time_stamp['count']=t_stamp['count'];
    print data;
    lock.release();


def send(data,portno):
    lock.acquire();
    global time_stamp;
    t_stamp={'pClock':0, 'lClock':0,'count':0};
    t_stamp['lClock']=max(time_stamp['lClock'],time_stamp['pClock']);
    if(t_stamp['lClock']==time_stamp['lClock']):
        time_stamp['count']=time_stamp['count']+1;
    else:
        time_stamp['count']=0;
    t_stamp['pClock']=time_stamp['pClock'];
    t_stamp['count']=time_stamp['count'];

    #update the time_stamp object to hold the event timestamp
    time_stamp['lClock']=t_stamp['lClock'];
    time_stamp['pClock']=t_stamp['pClock'];
    time_stamp['count']=t_stamp['count'];
    client_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
    client_socket.connect(("localhost",portno));
    client_socket.send(pickle.dumps(t_stamp));
    client_socket.close();
    lock.release();


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create a global lock for mutual exclusion
    global lock;
    lock=threading.RLock();
        #create an ntp object
    ntp=Ntp();
    #create a time-stamp object
    global time_stamp;
    time_stamp= {'pClock':0, 'lClock':0,'count':0};
        #launch a server thread
    server_thread=server(int(sys.argv[1]));
    server_thread.start();
    while 1:
        data=raw_input("Enter some text to send");
        portno=raw_input("Enter portno");
        if(data!="quit"):
            thread.start_new_thread(send,(data,int(portno)));   
        else:
            break;
        print "Exiting";
```

Comment: I have the feeling that the AgTime and the Ntp classes are not actually useful. Also, the indentation of the last line looks wrong to me.

Comment: AgTime is not useful but NTP class is.

Comment: I do see where we create an instance of ntp but I cannot see where the time() fonction is used. (If I missed something, let's pretend it's because I am not fully awaken yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to review the `Ntp` class. As you'll see, there's plenty here for one answer.

1. There's no documentation. What is this class supposed to do? What value does the `time` method return?
2. There are some "tells" that you have come from a C background, and are not yet a fluent Python programmer: you have unnecessary semi-colons at the ends of lines, and unnecessary parentheses around the condition in `if` statements.
3. The code is not portable to Python 3:

   ```
    >>> Ntp().time()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "cr41537.py", line 20, in time
        client.sendto(self.msg, self.address)
    TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
   ```

For portability to Python 3 you need `msg` to be a `bytes` object, not a `str`.

1. `Ntp` is a ["classic" or "old-style" class](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). This means that it doesn't support the [`super`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) function, making it inconvenient to subclass. You should make new-style classes unless you have a good reason not to, by inheriting from `object`:

   ```
    class Ntp(object):
   ```
2. It's not clear that there's any need for a class here. There's no persistent state, and just one method, so a function would work just as well and be simpler.
3. In this line:

   ```
    self.msg = '\x1b'+47*'\0'
   ```

it is not at all clear where the expression comes from. What does it mean, and how can I check that you got it right?

By reference to the NTP standard in [RFC 5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905), it looks as though this decodes as version = 3 and mode = client. I would try to be much more explicit here as to how this packet is constructed, for example like this:

```
    # See section 7 of RFC 5905 for the structure of an NTP packet.
    fmt = '!BBbb3I4Q'
    version = 3
    mode = 3 # client mode
    msg = struct.pack(fmt, (version << 3) + mode, *[0]*10)
```

Note that `msg` is now a `bytes` object as required by Python 3.

1. You call [`socket.recvfrom`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) to get the address of the socket sending the data, but then you never use it. So why not just use [`socket.recv`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)?
2. You are only going to use the first 48 bytes of the returned packet, so there is no point in setting the `bufsize` argument to `socket.recv` to be any larger.
3. You decode the result like this:

   ```
    retval=struct.unpack("!12I",data);
    t = retval[10]
   ```

but looking at [RFC 5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905), this gets you the top 32 bits of the 64-bit transmit timestamp (the integer part). Why are you throwing away the bottom 32 bits? Python's [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module supports computation with microseconds, so it is worth having both. I would decode like it this:

```
    fmt = '!BBbb3I4Q'
    results = struct.unpack(fmt, data)
    tx_timestamp = results[10]
```

and then if I need to convert to seconds I can divide by 2<sup>32</sup>. Note also that I used the same format for decoding the received packet as I did for encoding the sent packet. This ensures consistency.

1. In this code:

   ```
    # reference time (in seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00)
    TIME1970 = 2208988800 # 1970-01-01 00:00:00
   ```

it is not clear where this value comes from. How would I check that you got it right? I would refer to figure 4 of RFC 5905 in the comment.

You could also consider computing this constant explicitly using Python's [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module, which would make its meaning clear:

```
    from datetime import datetime

    # Offset between NTP time and Unix epoch time in seconds.
    # See figure 4 of RFC 5905.
    TIME1970 = (datetime(1970, 1, 1) - datetime(1900, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

1. There is no attempt to correct for the transmission delay as described in section 8 of RFC 5905. You need something like this:

   ```
    import time

    # Make sure DNS lookup time is not included in delay calculation.
    address = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

    orig_time = time.time()
    client.sendto(msg, address[0][4])
    data = client.recv(48)
    dst_time = time.time()
    results = struct.unpack(fmt, data)
    recv_time = results[9] / 2.0**32
    tx_time = results[10] / 2.0**32

    # Estimate transmission delay: see section 8 of RFC 5905.
    delay = ((dst_time - orig_time) - (tx_time - recv_time)) / 2
   ```

Note that the purpose of calling [`socket.getaddrinfo`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) here (instead of passing `(host, port)` directly to `client.sendto`) is to avoid the time for the DNS lookup of `host` being included in the delay calculation.

1. The `time` method returns the result in an inconvenient format (as the number of seconds since the epoch). It would be more generally useful to Python programmers to return a [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, like this:

   ```
    from datetime import datetime

    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(tx_time - TIME1970 + delay)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your generous feed back. I've incorporated all the changes you have mentioned here into my code. I should be looking at some code base on github to pick up in python and proper design styles.

Comment: And yeah your guessed it right about my C background.